# How to verify JWT token in nodejs

Tags: node.js, reactjs, jwt

In my case I want to validate if the user is logged in or not using JWT library and nodejs for my backend. In in code I cant validate the user if the user is logged in or not. it always says user not authenticated.

This is my validation function from my middleware

```
const validateToken = (req, res, next) => {
    const accessToken = decode["jwtToken"];

    if(!accessToken) {
        return res.json({error: "User not authenticated"});
    }else{
        try{
            const validToken = verify(accessToken, "Secret");
    
            if(validToken){
                console.log("user authenticated");
                req.authenticated = true;
                return next;
            }
        }catch (err) {
            return res.json({error: err});
        }
    }
}
```

And this is the code that will automatically make a token and store it into my cookie

```
const accessToken = createToken(user);

            res.cookie("jwtToken", accessToken, {
                maxAge: 60 * 60  * 12 * 1000, //12 hrs =======> 9sec  for testing 3 * 3 * 1000
                httpOnly: true,
            })

            res.json(accessToken);
```

Can someone can help me with my code?

Answer (score 0):

I solve my problem Everyone :-) I just miss the next declaration I used return next; instead of return next();

here is my code for my middleware

```
const validateToken = (req, res, next) => {
    const accessToken = req.cookies["token"];

    if(accessToken) {
        try{
            const validToken = jwt.verify(accessToken, "bluedragon14S");
    
            if(validToken){
                console.log("user authenticated");
                req.authenticated = true;
                return next();
            }
        }catch (err) {
            return res.json({error: err});
        }
    }else{
        return res.json({error: "User not authenticated"});
    }
}
```

I hope it helps the other students has same error with me. Happy coding ;-)